# Dynamic filter in Django

Tags: python, django

In my app, I have a form. Depending of the form, one or many filters could be configured by the user.

In my view, I have for exemple :

```
query = Test.objects.filter(filter1 = request.post['filter1'], filter2 = request.post['filter2'], filter3 = request.post['filter3'])
```

So, sometimes filter1, filter2 or filter3 could not exist.

If any filters doesn't exist, I just want to ignore the filter.

I could do a script with many "IF" conditions but may be there is a smart solution ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Creare a dictionary with the arguments and call `filter` like `.filter(**your_dict)`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
filters = {}

for key, value in request.post.items():
    if key in ['filter1', 'filter2', 'filter3']:
        filters[key] = value

Test.objects.filter(**filters)
```

Where the list is a list of keys that you are intending to filter by

---

**Edit**

As [Thomas Junk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411645/thomas-junk) suggested you can make it a lot cleaner with a comprehension:

```
filters = {
    key: value
    for key, value in request.post.items()
    if key in ['filter1', 'filter2', 'filter3']
}

Test.objects.filter(**filters)
```

Comment: Depending on Taste, one could write a comprehension. But this seems to do the trick.

Comment: Great ! Thank you !

Comment: quick question: how can use something like greater than or less than in this approach?

Comment: @krishnalodha you could have the key/param be `filter1__gte=10`

Answer (score 2):

This code solved my problem:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
        filters = {}
        for key, value in request.GET.items():
            if value != '':
                filters[key] = value
        filter_list=Pet.objects.filter(**filters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
import ast


def query_to_dict(query) -> dict:
    filters = {}
    for field, value in query.items(): #  <- param and value like ?param1=True
        filters[field] = ast.literal_eval(str(value)) #  <- parse list/str/bool

    return filters

def event_view(request):
    events = Event.objects.filter(
        Q(**query_to_dict(request.GET))
    )

    return Response(
        EventsSerializer(events, many=True).data
    )
```

In this example:

`ast` - module which will help to parse bool values and lists

`request.GET` - this is your query params `?param1=True&param2="[1, 2]"`. Make sure to pass params in way like `?title="hello"` - using double quotes

`query_to_dict` - function which will convert query params to python dict. So you can pass this dict to your `Event.objects.filter`.

Benefit of using filtering this way, you can pass `?id__in="[1, 2]"` something like this and it will work. I can't say for sure how it secure or not, but for some complex filtering or bool fields filtering it is perfect.