# Dynamic filtering in Django 3

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I'm new in Django. I'm searching ways to create dynamic filtering for my project. I can't find an easy way of doing it.

I need to be able to sort, and filter for 5 different categories. And search among these results.

I am using genericListView. Could anyone please help me by giving recommendations and example snippets for easy understanding?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic filter in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182481/dynamic-filter-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

There are two packages you can use:

1. `django-filters`
2. `django-haystack`

I would recommend `django-filters`.
You can have a look at the documentation here: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/